# Female mosquito fate in absence of food

Tags: entomology, ecology, food, life-history

What happens to female mosquitoes which want to lay egg but couldn't find mammal host for blood, will that mosquito simply die, if no mammals in area would mosquitoes will be absent too?

Comment: Interesting question. Mosquitoes are pretty much ubiquitous except in Antarctica, so lack of food evidently isn't a problem for the species as a whole. Not all mosquitoes feed exclusively on mammals - Wikipedia says ["Thousands of species feed on the blood of various kinds of hosts, mainly vertebrates, including mammals, birds, reptiles, amphibians, and even some kinds of fish. Some mosquitoes also attack invertebrates, mainly other arthropods."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the function of having blood meals is to produce eggs but not for surviving. Some exceptions are for overwintering species which uses some blood-feed meals to [survive during winter such as Culex pipiens](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.113233).

In absence of blood host (the host depends on mosquito species and can range from fish to mammals!) and after mating, the female would just keep looking for a host (and some sugar source to stay alive) until she dies. So there is no reason for not living as long as in the case she would have found one or several hosts in her entire life (a couple of weeks usually).